# <router-outlet> doesn't work in Angular 9

Tags: angular

I met some problems with angular 9,  doesn't work.
My file like this:
[image]

routes.ts

```
import { LayoutComponent } from './../layout/layout.component';
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LayoutComponent, children: [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: () => import('./dashboard/dashboard.module').then((m) => m.DashboardModule)},
    { path: 'table', loadChildren: () => import('./table/table.module').then((m) => m.TableModule)},
    { path: 'form', loadChildren: () => import('./form/form.module').then((m) => m.FormModule)}
  ]}
];
```

app-routes.moudule.ts

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { routes } from './routes';

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutesModule {}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { LayoutModule } from './layout/layout.module';
import { AppRoutesModule } from './routes/app-routes.module';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    LayoutModule,
    AppRoutesModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

layout.component.html

```
<p>layout works! works</p>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

layout.module.ts

```
import { LayoutComponent } from './layout.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [LayoutComponent],
  exports: [LayoutComponent]
})
export class LayoutModule {}
```

When I run ng serve, it always indicates:

> Blockquote

ERROR in src/app/layout/layout.component.html:2:1 - error NG8001: 'router-outlet' is not a known element:
    1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

```
2 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/layout/layout.component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './layout.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component LayoutComponent.
```

> Blockquote

Somebody could help me figure it out?

Also, in layout.component.html file,  doesn't show the children content, such as form component, table component, or dashboard component.

any suggestions?

Comment: `LayoutModule` and `AppModule` are different modules, you are declaring the routes only in the `AppModule`, the `LayoutModule` doesn't know about the router

Comment: I import layoutmodule in app.module.ts, where I also import routing module, so the layout module should know the route. Is that right?

Comment: I think you are complicating stuff, if anything, you have to import the RoutingModule into the LayoutModule so it knows about the router-outlet; if the component that will use the routes is the LayoutComponent, not the AppComponent, then the LayoutComponent should have the routing module imported into it

Comment: But my I idea is app.module just for entrance where it use route to show layout component that is only header and sidemenu, and then layout component using route to show it children, which is the detail contents. That is why I put my code like this way. However, my question is why angular think router-outlet is not a know element, but i import routermodule where I import layout module too.

Comment: I recommend going through the Angular Docs again, I get what you are trying to do, the thing is Angular doesn't work that way, in order for a *Module* to have access to directives or component, those must be imported *inside that* module, importing the module into another module which has what you need won't work, because each module only has access to what's in them... In your case, AppModule knows about router-outlet because it is directly imported in it, but LayoutModule doesn't because the routing module is only in AppModule, not in LayoutModule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go about it.

You have the following Modules:

- AppModule
- LayoutModule
- AppsRouteModule (which is just a routing module)

In Angular, when you create a module, that module only has access to the components, directives, etc that you declare inside it.

**AppModule**

This AppModule has access to any Component or Directive you declare in it, or any other element you *export* from one of the Modules inside (Like LayoutModule)

```
import { LayoutModule } from './layout/layout.module';
import { AppRoutesModule } from './routes/app-routes.module';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    LayoutModule,
    AppRoutesModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**LayoutModule**

Then we have the LayoutModule, which only has the LayoutComponent declared inside.

```
import { LayoutComponent } from './layout.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [LayoutComponent],
  exports: [LayoutComponent]
})
export class LayoutModule {}
```

With this setup, everything you **export** from the LayoutModule will be available to be used in the AppModule, but the LayoutModule won't have access to what's declared in the AppModule, it is a child of the AppModule, if you will.

Since the routing module is only declared in the AppModule, the LayoutModule doesn't know about it, Angular simply does not handle Modules like that, if you want to use the routing in the LayoutModule, import it in that module, it you want to use the routing module in both (which I don't think is a good thing) you should create a SharedModule, import and export the routing module in there, and then import the SharedModule in both the App and Layout modules.

Comment: Thanks for your patient explanation. I tried your suggestions, and it works. However, I found another weird question. I import just RouterModule (but not AppRoutesModule I created) in layout module, it is still working. Why? The RouterModule angular owns should not know the Routes I created, but why the routing is still correct?

Comment: I'm guessing that the routes you have on AppModule are global, so if your routerLink points to that specific rout, it'll simply match, since the routes are already loaded in the application thanks to the AppModule

Comment: another thing I found in my code what i just tested is in my layout module, even though I don't export layout component and header component, the code is still working. The content in layout and header component is still rendering. these means if the A module import to B module, in A module several components are declared, but not exported in A module, after import into B module, B module still can recognize components in A module , and can working with them. Is that making sense?

Comment: If you are using your component inside the module it is declared, then it will work without issues, if you are using LayoutComponent inside your LayoutModule, then it will work fine, regardless of LayoutModule exporting anything to AppModule

Comment: you are absolutely right. Thanks so much for your nice reply, and it help me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

you must import RouterModule

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild()]
})
export class LayoutModule {}
```

a better approach

**layout.component.html**

```
<p>layout works! works</p>
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-layout>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</app-layout>
```

Comment: thanks for you answer. In my layout.modue.ts file I export layout component, and import it into app.module.ts where I import routemodule, it should work, is it right?

Comment: I would not use routing in the layout

Comment: Yes, I don't use routing in layout module, that is why I don't import routermodule there, but instead, I export the layout component and import it to app.module.ts where I import routermodule, so logically layout router-outlet should work in my code. I don't know where the issue it. Could you give me more explanation?

Comment: you use the component RouterOutlet in layout that belongs to RoutingModule, that's why he gets an error

Comment: @John uses the recommendation I made above, it is much better

Comment: Hi Crhis, I understan that router-outlet belong to routermodule, like I said, I export this layout module to app.module, where I import routermodule, I want to know why it can't recognize router-outlet

Comment: For you method, I prefer to leave only <router-outlet></router-outlet> in app.component.html to make it more lean

Comment: Modules only manage what is imported into them, if you import RoutingModule in AppComponent then evey component in that module will be able to use it, but since LayoutModule is *another* module, it only manages what's importet in it. This is why it is recommended to create a SharedModule which you would import eveywhere you need the same components, directives, etc. In your case, you should be managing routes from a single place, which is the AppModule, so LayoutModule won't know about it, importing in AppModule doesn't matter, what's inside LayoutModule doesn't know about router-module

Comment: @IvanS95 RoutingModule should not be in sharing module,  has only two options or use ng-content or import routes into the layout

Comment: @IvanS95 you are right, module manages its own components. however, in my layout module, I exports laymout component, and import it in app module, so layout component should know routermodule, is it right?

Comment: LayoutModule does not know about the components outside the module